# I want to display table instead of displaying hi if i click menu 1

Tags: javascript

in this if i click menu1 hi will display.instead of that i want a to diaplay a table with 5 rows and 6 colunns.any one help me

### JavaScript

```
function displayDate1() {
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=" hi";
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML="";
}
function displayDate2() {
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML="Bye";
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML="";
}
```

### HTML

```
<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="displayDate1()">Menu 1</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);"     onclick="displayDate2()">Menu 2</a> 
<p id="demo1"> </p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Comment: is it a JavaScript Question or PHP ?

Comment: @swapnesh It's a *write-this-for-me* problem.

Comment: @BackinaFlash very well mentioned :)

Comment: i am going to replace php tag with javascript ..

Answer (score 1):

Replace displayDate1() with something like:

```
function displayDate1() {
    var html_table = '<table>' +
           '    <tr>' +
           '      <td>Blah</td>' +
           '    </tr>' +
           '</table>';

    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML= html_table;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML="";
}
```

Note this is not a PHP question. It's a Javascript question. You'll also need to fill out the table located in the html_table to have 5 rows and 6 columns.

As an side, you may consider looking at jQuery. It makes something like this much easier.

Comment: i want a structure of a table with 4 rows and 6 columns if i click menu1

Comment: Er, then fill out the code I provided? Not particularly difficult.

Comment: if i create a table in html file means how can i call it in javascript

Comment: I already showed you above. If my blatantly giving you the answer doesn't help, you may consider learning Javascript first.

Comment: please send some example coding to my mail arivu.vjs09@gmail.com

Comment: Would be a pointless endeavor, as i'd simply send you what I typed above as IT'S THE ANSWER (unless of course, you care to pay my consulting fee). Again, I reiterate, go learn Javascript before continuing.